# Pestaña activa muestra información de otra pestaña

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, active

Resulta que tengo un problema con las pestañas en una seccion de la pagina que estoy trabajando.
Cuando se carga la pagina, aparece activa la pestaña Propietarios, pero la informacion que muestra (tablas, boton, etc) es de la pestaña que esta al lado, la de Propiedades.

Si se hace click en la pestaña Propiedades y luego vuelvo a Propietarios ahi si muestra la informacion de esa misma pestaña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
    <!-- Tabs navs --><section id="tabs" class="project-tab">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <nav>
                            <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="true">Propietarios</a>
                                
                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="false">Propiedades</a>

                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Clientes</a>

                                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-action-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-action" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-action" aria-selected="false">Acciones</a>
                                
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                            
                                <hr>

                                <!-- Modal para la cargar nueva propiedad -->
                                
            

<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="nuevo_propiedad" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Propiedad</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
     
     
    
     
 <form action="menu_gutierrez.php?id_cliente=<?php echo $id_cliente  ; ?>" method="POST">
     
 
 <div class="form-row">
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
                
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect022">Propietario:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="select_propietario" name="select_propietario" required>
            <option selected>Seleccioná: </option>
            
            
      <?php      $query_1 = "SELECT * from personas where id_cliente = '$id_cliente' and tipo_persona = 'propietario' ";
          $result_tasks_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_1);    

          while($row_1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_tasks_1)) { ?>
                    
            <option value=<?php echo $row_1['id_persona']; ?> ><?php echo $row_1['apellido']. ", " . $row_1['nombre']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            
            </div>
        
            
     </div>
    </div>
        
</div>
 
 
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="dire_propiedad">Dirección</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dire_propiedad" name="dire_propiedad" >
    </div>
 </div>



<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="zona_propiedad">Zona</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zona_propiedad" name="zona_propiedad" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="llaves_propiedad">Llaves</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="llaves_propiedad" name="llaves_propiedad" >
    </div>
    

 </div>
    
    
 <div class="form-row">
   
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <div class="input-group mb-6">
                <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect022">Tipo:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="tipo_propiedad" name="tipo_propiedad" required>
            <option selected>Seleccioná: </option>
            
<option value="1">Vivienda</option>
<option value="2">Local</option>
<option value="3">Cochera</option>
<option value="4">Departamento</option>
<option value="5">Campo</option>
<option value="6">Quinta</option>
<option value="7">Oficina</option>
<option value="8">Galpon</option>
<option value="9">Torre</option>
            
             
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-6">
                <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect022">Ambientes:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="ambientes_propied" name="ambientes_propied" required>
            <option selected>Seleccioná: </option>

<option value="1">1 Ambiente</option>
<option value="2">2 Ambientes</option>
<option value="3">3 Ambientes</option>
<option value="4">4 Ambientes</option>
<option value="5">2 Ambientes c/Desp</option>
<option value="6">2 Ambientes y 1/2</option>


    
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-6">
                <div class="input-group-prepend" >
                <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect022">Situación:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="situacion_propied" name="situacion_propied" required>
            <option selected>Seleccioná: </option>

<option value="1">Frente</option>
<option value="2">Contra Frente</option>
<option value="3">Interior</option>


    
            </select>
    </div>
    </div>

 </div>
 
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="estado_propiedad">Estado</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado_propiedad" name="estado_propiedad" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="habit_propiedad">Habitaciones</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="habit_propiedad" name="habit_propiedad" >
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="banos_propiedad">Baños</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="banos_propiedad" name="banos_propiedad" >
    </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="parcela_propiedad">Parcela m2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="parcela_propiedad" name="parcela_propiedad" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="const_propiedad">Construído m2</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="const_propiedad" name="const_propiedad" >
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="precio_propiedad">Precio de Venta</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio_propiedad" name="precio_propiedad" >
    </div>

 </div>
 
  
    
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="notas_propiedad">Notas</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="notas_propiedad" name="notas_propiedad" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
 </div> 
  



 
  
 
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_nueva_propiedad" >Guardar y Salir</button>
</form>
     
    
     
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--fin de modal-->
                                
                                 <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover" id="dataTable_Actividades" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                 <button type="button" class="btns-nueva" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevo_propiedad"><i class=" far fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true" style="margin: 0 3px"></i>Nueva Propiedad</button>
                                        <thead class="thead-light">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><small>Dirección</small></th>
                                                <th><small>Zona</small></th>
                                                 <th><small>Propietario</small></th>
                                                
                                                <th><small></small></th>
                                                
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                       
                                        <tbody  id="tbody_manzana_search">
                                            <?php
                                                        $query_movi = "SELECT * FROM `temp_propiedades` inner JOIN personas on temp_propiedades.propietario = personas.id_persona  where temp_propiedades.id_cliente = '$id_cliente'";
                                                    $result_movi = mysqli_query($conn, $query_movi);    

                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_movi)) { ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['direccion']; ?></small></td>
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['zona']; ?></small></td>
                                                        
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></small></td>
                                                                                                                
                                                    <td>
                                                         <a href="propiedad_detal.php?xdcf=<?php echo $id ."&id_propiedad=" . $row['id_propiedad'] ;?>" class="btn btn-secondary bg-success">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ver" ></i>
                                                         </a>
                                                         
                                                        
                                                         
                                                    </td>
                                                    
                                                
                                                    </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>  
                                         
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                            
                            <hr>

                            <!-- Modal para la cargar de nueva propietario -->

                         

<div class="modal fade" id="nuevo_propietario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Propietario</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
     
     
    
     
     <form action="menu_gutierrez.php?id_cliente=<?php echo $id_cliente  ; ?>" method="POST">
     
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="nombre_propietario">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_propietario" name="nombre_propietario" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="apellido_propietario">Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido_propietario" name="apellido_propietario" placeholder="Apellido">
    </div>
    
   </div>
   
    
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="celu_propietario">Celular</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celu_propietario" name="celu_propietario">
    </div>
  
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="tel_propietario">Teléfono</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tel_propietario" name="tel_propietario" >
    </div>
   
  </div>
  
  
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="dire_propietario">Dirección</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dire_propietario" name="dire_propietario" >
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="localidad_propietario">Localidad</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="localidad_propietario" name="localidad_propietario" >
    </div>
  
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="provincia_propietario">Provincia</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="provincia_propietario" name="provincia_propietario" >
    </div>
   
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    
        
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Tipo</label>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option selected>Elegir...</option>
    <option value="1">DNI</option>
    <option value="2">CUIT</option>
    <option value="3">L.C</option>
  </select>
</div>

    
      <label for="docu_propietario">Documento</label>
      <input type="number" max="99999999" class="form-control" id="docu_propietario" name="docu_propietario" required>
    </div>
  
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="mail_propietario">E-Mail</label>
      <input type="emmail" class="form-control" id="mail_propietario" name="mail_propietario" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="profesion_propietario">Profesión</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="profesion_propietario" name="profesion_propietario" placeholder="Profesión">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <label for="nacimiento_propietario">Nacimiento</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="nacimiento_propietario" name="nacimiento_propietario" >
    </div>

   
  </div>
  
  
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="notas_propietario">Notas</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="notas_propietario" name="notas_propietario" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
    

  
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_propietario" >Guardar y Salir</button>
</form>
     
    
     
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--fin de modal propietario-->
                            
                                 <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-hover" id="dataTable1" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                 <button type="button" class="btns-nueva" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevo_propietario"><i class="   far fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true" style="margin: 0 3px"></i>Nuevo Propietario</button>
                                        <thead class="thead-light">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><small>Nombre</small></th>
                                                <th><small>Apellido</small></th>
                                                   <th><small></small></th>
                                                   
                                                <th><small>Celular</small></th>
                                                <th><small>E-Mail</small></th>
                                                <th><small>Estado</small></th>
                                             
                                                
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                       
                                        <tbody  id="tbody_propietario_search">
                                            <?php
                                                    $query_movi = "SELECT * from personas where id_cliente = '$id_cliente' and tipo_persona = 'propietario' ";
                                                    $result_movi = mysqli_query($conn, $query_movi);    

                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_movi)) { ?>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></small></td>
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['apellido']; ?></small></td>
                                                        
                                                        <td>
                                                         <a href="persona_detail.php?xdcf=<?php echo $id ."&id_persona=" . $row['id_persona'] ;?>"
                                                         class="btn btn-secondary bg-info">
                                                        <i class="far fa-address-card" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Ver" ></i>
                                                         </a>
                                                    
                                                    
                                                         
                                                    </td>
                                                    
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['celu']; ?></small></td>
                                                        <td><small><?php echo $row['mail']; ?></small></td>
                                                        <td><small><?php                                                        
                                                        
                                                    if  ($row['estado'] == 0) { 
                                                    echo "Activo";
                                                    }else{
                                                        
                                                        echo "Cancelado";
                                                    }; 
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        ?></small></td>
                                                        
                                                                                                                
                                                    
                                                    
                                                
                                                    </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>  
                                         
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
                               <hr>
```

No se cual sera el problema. Quizas estoy buscando el error en el archivo equivocado.

Probe cambiando esta parte de codigo que marca al nav-home por el q seria nav-profile (el de propietario) pero no lo soluciona.

Comment: ¿Para qué usas ventanas modales dentro de las pestañas? En estos momentos no puedo reproducir tu problema, pero creo que no estás haciendo un uso adecuado de ellas en el interior de una pestaña con el contenido que deseas mostrar en la pestaña.

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te han proporcionado, tiene toda la pinta de que has habilitado dos pestañas a la vez por defecto o bien que has puesto la clase `active ` a una pestaña que no coincide con el contenido activo y por eso se ve el contenido erróneo.

Comment: Ya habia probado cambiar eso que me mencionaron abajo, pero se rompe peor :/

Comment: En un par de horas estaré en casa y podré reproducir tu problema. Si no lo solucionas para entonces me pondré con ello.

Comment: Qué versión de bootstrap usas?

Comment: @javdromero Si no mal recuerdo, es Bs4

Answer (score 1):

Las clases `show active` es la que debes de cambiar, en tu caso la tienes en la tab de `Propiedades`

```
<div class="tab-pane fade ***show active***" id="nav-home"....>
```

Pero debería de estar en la tab de `Propietarios`

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active " id="nav-profile"....>
```

Además sugiero mantener el orden de las tabs con los divs de contenido ya que genera confusión como ahora.

Comment: Hola! Si, eso ya habia probado cambiarlo pero al hacerlo, se buguea peor, porque asi directamente me muestra solo la informacion de Propiedades en las dos pestañas, tanto Propiedades (que esta bien) como en Propietarios

Comment: Debes de quitar esas clases del div nav-home. Lo que pasa es que debes de tener un estado inicial en tus divs. No puedes tener 2 tabs activas a la misma ves, por eso tienes problemas.